# cakephp: $belongsTo in model is not working

Tags: cakephp

table: graduate_applicants

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `graduate_applicants` (
  `grat_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `studentnum` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `QuarterID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`grat_id`)
)
```

table: stu_students

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stu_students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `studentid` int(9) default NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `studentid` (`studentid`),
 )
```

model：

```
class GraduateApplicant extends AppModel{

var $name = 'GraduateApplicant';

var $tablePrefix = '';

var $belongsTo = array('Student' => array('className' => 'Student','foreignKey' => false,''conditions' => array('Student.studentid=GraduateApplicant.studentnum'),'fields' => '','order' => ''),);

}
```

controller:

```
$list = $this->paginate('GraduateApplicant');
```

i can not understand why $list is empty ?

Comment: Did you include it in either the `contain` or `recursive` keys? Also your sample model has an extra quote in the `$belongsTo` definition before 'conditions'. Lastly, show your SQL.

Comment: why is fields set to ''?

Comment: Can you post your `Student` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP really makes your life easier if you set up your tables to properly reflect the relationships between them.  You could cut your code down by 90% because you don't have to try to manually specify the way the tables are linked.

```
students
---------------------------------------------
id   |   firstname   |   lastname   |   email


graduate_applicants
------------------------------------
id   |   student_id   |   quarter_id
```

Then your model would be simple:

```
class GraduateApplicant extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Student');

}
```

If it's an option, I would recommend setting up your database tables properly like this, instead of having the student ID columns called different things in different tables (`Student.studentid`, `GraduateApplicant.studentnum`)

And it will also make your life a lot easier if you name your models to properly reflect your table names. Your table is called `stu_students` but your model is called `Student`. You should either name your table `students` and your model `Student`, your table `stu_students` and your model `StuStudent`.